# en PHP obtener el dia 25 del mes anterior

Tags: php, datetime, datepicker

Mes gustaria poder seleccionar en mi consulta el dia 25 del mes anterior al presente sin importar que en el presente mes estemos a 2 o a 27 por ejemplo 
algo como : 
Dia de hoy 27/07/2018

```
<?=$date; ?>
```

Resultadio de $date

```
25/06/2018
```

e usado la consulta :

```
$lastday = date('t',strtotime('last month'));
```

Que me da como resultado el ultimo dia de el mes pasado pero yo quiero obtener el dia(25), mes(anterior al presente) y año (presente año)

Comment: lo estas comparando con un valor de la base de datos ?

Comment: no , lo quiero comparar con la fecha actual current_timestamp porejemplo

Comment: bueno, primero verifica los formatos de las fechas, ya que si no estoy mal el current trae primero el año/mes/dia

Comment: bueno ese era un ejemplo, el resultado que espero va mas por : $lastday = date('t/m/Y',strtotime('last month')); que me entrega 30/06/2018, yo deseo conseguir de manera logia 25/06/2018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preguntas por el mes anterior con mes y año y añades el día que quieras como string previo en `php`.

```
echo "25-".date("m-Y", strtotime("- 1 month"));
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!! , para acoplar a lo que busco le hice el siguiente cambio:echo "25-".date("m/Y", strtotime("- 1 month")); y lo atrape en una variable $date .

Comment: Me alegro que te sirva, no me di cuenta de que tenías la fecha con formato /, así que perfecto. Añade la también tras el día "25/".

Comment: $date = "25/".date("m/Y", strtotime("- 1 month")) ; listo :)